# Regular Expression to match Salutation

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, regular-language

I used the following regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(Mr. .*|MR. .*|MRS. .*|Mrs. .*|MS. .*|Ms. .*|DR. .*|Dr. .*)", ErrorMessage = "Greeting must begin with Mr., Mrs., Ms., or Dr. and be followed by a name.")]
 public string? Greeting { get; set; }
```

How can I force user to enter space after `Mr.`, `MR.`, `MRs.`, `Mrs.`, then at least one character after the space.

For example: if they enter `Mr. Joe Doe` or `Mr. Joe` is valid but they enter `Mr.` with space only or `Mr.` without space is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues

`.` matches "any character" so saying `Mr.` allows someone to write `Mra` `Mrb` etc - put a `\` before it or put it in a character class (surround it with `[` `]`)

`*` means "zero or more of" so a regex of `Mr. .*` allows them to write zero characters for the name. To quantify "one or more" we use `+` instead of `*`

If you want to do away with repetitive elements you could

```
(M[rRsS]|M(RS|rs)|D[rR])\. \w+
```

The first one takes care of Mr and Ms, second takes care of Mrs, third Dr, then is the common element of "literally a period" followed by a succession of word characters

Comment: thanks Calius one thing with `RegularExpression(@"^(Mr\. .|MR\. .|MRS\. .|Mrs\. .|MS\. .|Ms\. .|DR\. .|Dr\. .)"` it only accept one character after space

Comment: You'll need to use `.+` - I forgot that regular expression attributes match the whole expression

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace every * with +

```
^(Mr. .+|MR. .+|MRS. .+|Mrs. .+|MS. .+|Ms. .+|DR. .+|Dr. .+)
```

I believe this could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this to get started

```
^[Mr\.]+[ ]+[A-Za-z]{0,25}[ ]?[A-za-z]{1,25}
```

This should match the use cases you gave.

The backslash escapes the period so it matches a literal period.

The curly brackets give a range of how many patterns are allowed of the grouping before it.

The question mark makes the bracket grouping before it optional.

Also, give this site a shot to try out your regex in real time. https://regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```cs
^(?:[DM][rR][sS]?|M[Ss])\. .+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/lgdP4l/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```cs
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [DM]                     any character of: 'D', 'M'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [rR]                     any character of: 'r', 'R'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [sS]?                    any character of: 's', 'S' (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    M                        'M'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [Ss]                     any character of: 'S', 's'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```